# LinearLayout align text to center view with drawableLeft

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to align the image to textview.

What I want it to look like:
[image: expected result]

What it actually looks like:

[image: Actual Result]

Please ignore the background color, image size. The issue is related to aligning the image with the text view.

I have tried the following code:

```
<LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="2">
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_checkin"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:text="@string/check_in"
                android:drawablePadding="-20sp"
                style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21"
               />
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_checkout"
                android:text="@string/check_out"
                style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21"
                android:gravity="center" 
               />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Note: I have used `android:drawablePadding="-20sp"` but without success.

Also tried:

```
       <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linear_today_attendance"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:stretchColumns = "*"
               >
               <TableRow 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_checkin"
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:text="@string/check_in"
                    android:drawablePadding="-20sp"
                    style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21"
                   />
               <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_checkout"
                    android:text="@string/check_out"
                    style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21"
                    android:gravity="center" 
                   />
               </TableRow>
       </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest option, but it should work:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_checkin"
            android:text="@string/check_in"
            style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_checkout"
            android:text="@string/check_out"
            style="@style/roboto4F4F4Flight21" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the `TextView` in a `LinearLayout` worked for me. Give it a shot.

```
// FYI, all columns are stretched using android:stretchColumns="*"
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    // and again same thing for the next item
    <LinearLayout...>
        <TextView.../>
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```